# Question About Loop Optimization and Speed

Tags: python, optimization, python-requests

This is the gist of my code:

```
while (int(price) > targetPrice):

    try:
        details = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
        var1 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))
        var2 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))
        var3 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))    
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        print('Error')
```

Essentially, I have a loop that is constantly fetching a webpage and scraping desired pieces of data. The issue I have is that I need this loop to run as fast as possible. It takes an average of .33 seconds for the loop to iterate one time and I want to get this number as low as I can. The information I'm fetching changes every so often, and I need to fetch it as soon as that change occurs.

I found the reason it takes this long is due to the request I make. There is a lot of HTML present when I only require about 5 lines that are in the same spot within the HTML. Is there a way to have the request fetch specific lines of the HTML and ignore everything I don't need?

The HTML being extracted is from this page: https://www.roblox.com/catalog/6803405665/Gucci-Dionysus-Bag

Multi-threading isn't really what I'm after because the goal is to try and get the loop to iterate as fast as possible. Multi-threading, to my knowledge and testing, just allows the loop to run asynchronously but will still run at .33 seconds per iteration.

I believe this to be an optimization question if anything. Any assistance would be appreciated. If any further information is required, please let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: You probably want to pre-compile the patterns with `re.compile` to save it being done on each loop. However your code makes a network request, which is likely to be at least an order of magnitudes slower than anything else, and can't be optimised away.

Comment: How much is "a lot" of data? The server decides what gets sent over, so unless you're dealing with a server that lets you control what specific lines of HTML are received through the request parameters, you can't pick and choose what gets sent as part of the response. I'd surmise that it's the request causing most of the slowdown, but without profiling your code, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: I suppose "a lot" of data was vague, I'll edit it and post the HTML that I fetch so individual judgment can be made. In regards to compiling, I don't really have very much experience with it, would this still be an option if the data changes every so often?

Comment: Okay. How much time does it take to make the request alone per iteration?

Comment: Average is about the same at .33 - .36 seconds

Comment: From the HTML above, viewing the page source is essentially what the text is in my code, and the only lines I take data from are lines 903-908

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would try would be to use requests.Session
according to the doc https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It >also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and >will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to >the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result >in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

Instanciate the Session outside your while loop:

```
s = requests.Session()
while (int(price) > targetPrice):

    try:
        details = s.get(url, headers=headers).text
        var1 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))
        var2 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))
        var3 = (int)(re.search('desired-string(\d+)', details).group(1))    
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        print('Error')
```

If this is still not enough, maybe move to asynchronous requests https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/

Comment: This actually did reduce the loop iteration time. The Average went from around .33 seconds to .25 seconds. Thank you for your help.